# Passing special characters over socket connection

Tags: android, sockets, special-characters

I have built a chat application in Android powered by sockets. The messages send and receive fine, so long as the user does not send messages with special characters, ie. `Hey, it's me`, will not work, but `Hey its me`, will, the comma and apostrophe prevent the message from being delivered.

I attempted using `URLEncoder`, but that did not allow the unique characters to be sent.

Sending message method:

```
  public String sendMessage(String username, String tousername, String message, String campaign_id, String location_id)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String params = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.username, "UTF-8")
                + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.password, "UTF-8")
                + "&to=" + URLEncoder.encode(tousername, "UTF-8")
                + "&message=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8")
                + "&campaign_id=" + URLEncoder.encode(campaign_id, "UTF-8")
                + "&location_id=" + URLEncoder.encode(location_id, "UTF-8")
                + "&action=" + URLEncoder.encode("sendMessage", "UTF-8")
                + "&gcmregid=" + gcmRegistrationID
                + "&";
        Log.i("PARAMS", params);
        return socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);
    }
```

with

`SocketerInterface socketOperator = new Socketer(this);`

and Socketer class as:

```
public class Socketer implements SocketerInterface {
    // Have to set the proper ports that apache is runnign on as well as your
    // computers IP address: ie. ip:4430 or 800
    Global ipAddress = new Global();
    private final String AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://"
             // + ipAddress.getIpAddress() + ":80/AndroidChatterDatabase/";   // Google Compute Engine Access
            //+ ipAddress.getIpAddress() + ":4430/AndroidChatterDatabase/"; // Localhost access

              + ipAddress.getFeastChatServer(); // For Heroku access

    private int listeningPort = 0;

    private static final String HTTP_REQUEST_FAILED = null;

    private HashMap<InetAddress, Socket> sockets = new HashMap<InetAddress, Socket>();

    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    private boolean listening;

    private class ReceiveConnection extends Thread {
        Socket clientSocket = null;

        public ReceiveConnection(Socket socket) {
            this.clientSocket = socket;
            Socketer.this.sockets.put(socket.getInetAddress(), socket);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // PrintWriter out = new
                // PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.v("XML MESSAGE", inputLine);

                    if (inputLine.equals("exit") == false) {// as long as have
                                                            // noted exited yet,
                                                            // will continuing
                                                            // reading in


                        Log.v("XML MESSAGE", inputLine);
                        // appManager.messageReceived(inputLine);
                    } else {
                        clientSocket.shutdownInput();
                        clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
                        clientSocket.close();
                        Socketer.this.sockets.remove(clientSocket
                                .getInetAddress());
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("ReceiveConnection.run: when receiving connection ", "");
            }
        }
    }

    public Socketer(Manager appManager) {
    }

    public String sendHttpRequest(String params) {
        URL url;
        String result = new String();
        try {
            url = new URL(AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS);
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            out.println(params);
            out.close();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result = result.concat(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (result.length() == 0) {
            result = HTTP_REQUEST_FAILED;
        }

        // This is the output of the datastream from the server ie. <data>
        // (bunch of data...etc) </data>

        // Testing to remove <head/> tag from Google App Engine
        //return result.replace("<head/>","");
        return result;

    }

    public int startListening(int portNo) {
        listening = true;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNo);
            this.listeningPort = portNo;
        } catch (IOException e) {

            // e.printStackTrace();
            this.listeningPort = 0;
            return 0;
        }

        while (listening) {
            try {
                new ReceiveConnection(serverSocket.accept()).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                return 2;
            }
        }

        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception server socket",
                    "Exception when closing server socket");
            return 3;
        }

        return 1;
    }

    public void stopListening() {
        this.listening = false;
    }

    public void exit() {
        for (Iterator<Socket> iterator = sockets.values().iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext();) {
            Socket socket = (Socket) iterator.next();
            try {
                socket.shutdownInput();
                socket.shutdownOutput();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        sockets.clear();
        this.stopListening();
    }

    public int getListeningPort() {

        return this.listeningPort;
    }

}
```

How can I format/encode to allow sending these messages?

Comment: Send and receive how? With what code? You can't seriously believe that the sockets themselves are suppressing the special characters, but that's the only conclusion one can draw from your question.

Comment: Why the final `"&"`? That's not correct URL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses UTF-16 for internal String representation, but it looks like you are using UTF-8, but you aren't doing anything special to convert it from UTF-8 when reading it from BufferedReader.  In the params, try specifying UTF-16 instead.

From the [Java String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format

Comment: It's a PHP insert issue, just found it

Comment: @Sauron So the question is now pointless as the problem has nothing to do with the code you posted. Please delete it.